# How create a better searching queryin MySQL

Tags: mysql, search

I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE NAME LIKE '%GTX 980%'
```

This works just fine but sometimes when I type for instance GTX 790 or any other it would not show results.

Is there any way that query would search from rows on behalf of words separated by whitespaces for example in 'GTX 790' query should search with both keywords like GTX and 790 and show the combined result!!

Comment: You may wish to investigate MySQL's FULLTEXT search capability.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how would it be optimized to FULLTEXT search?

Comment: Split GTX and 980, make two different queries, thus increasing the chance that GTX will be found. Or even make 3 or more queries like %TX, since it also can be CTX or RTX; likewise, GT%, since it also can be GTR etc. Put some proper business logic in your code, which will increase the efficiency for sure, however, will decrease performance due to large number of queries running at the same time. My suggestion will also be to consider Elastic Search.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand, you are looking for anything with either GTX or 790?

try:

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE NAME LIKE '%GTX%' or NAME LIKE '%980%'
```

this will search for anything containing at least one of the strings.

Comment: No actually this GTX 790 is stored in a variable of php line $name="GTX 790"

Comment: and if the text is "GTX 790" what rows from the database are you expecting to see? and what rows don't you want go get?

can you put a couple of example rows so i could understand what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Lemme give you a scenario like in a website if a person enters GTX 790 and due nonexistence of product now rows would be fetched! But if GTX 790 is searched in a manner like 'GTX' and '790' (two separated keywords) then there might be possibility that some of the rows would be returned that matches to GTX and those matches to 790

Comment: so if you need the exact string "GTX 790" - use:

     WHERE NAME = 'GTX 790'

if you need each word by its own, then split you the string by spaces ' ' and for every word you get to:

   WHERE NAME LIKE '%WORD_1%' or NAME LIKE '%WORD_2%' and so on...